# google drive picker and DriveApp is not defined error

Tags: javascript, html, google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, google-drive-picker

This is my google drive file choose api code.

when I tried to run this code showing me error like DriveApp is not defined.

In this code I am getting error on that particular part:

```
function getOAuthToken() {
      DriveApp.getRootFolder();
      return ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
    }
```

I am referring the google documentation but still I am getting those error.
**https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons.css">
  <script>
    // IMPORTANT: Replace the value for DEVELOPER_KEY with the API key obtained
    // from the Google Developers Console.
    var DEVELOPER_KEY = 'key';
    var DIALOG_DIMENSIONS = {width: 600, height: 425};
    var pickerApiLoaded = false;

    function onApiLoad() {
      gapi.load('picker', {'callback': function() {
        pickerApiLoaded = true;
      }});
     }

    function getOAuthToken() {
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createPicker)
          .withFailureHandler(showError).getOAuthToken();
    }

    function createPicker(token) {
      var uploadView = new google.picker.DocsUploadView().setIncludeFolders(true);
      if (pickerApiLoaded && token) {
        var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
            // Instruct Picker to display only spreadsheets in Drive. For other
            // views, see https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/#otherviews
            .addView(uploadView)
            .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.NAV_HIDDEN)
            .hideTitleBar()
            .setOAuthToken(token)
            .setDeveloperKey(DEVELOPER_KEY)
            .setCallback(pickerCallback)
            .setOrigin(google.script.host.origin)
            .setSize(DIALOG_DIMENSIONS.width - 2,DIALOG_DIMENSIONS.height - 2)
            .build();
        picker.setVisible(true);
      } else {
        showError('Unable to load the file picker.');
      }
    }

    function pickerCallback(data) {
      var action = data[google.picker.Response.ACTION];
      if (action == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
        var doc = data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS][0];
        var id = doc[google.picker.Document.ID];
        var url = doc[google.picker.Document.URL];
        var title = doc[google.picker.Document.NAME];
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML =
            '<b>You chose:</b><br>Name: <a href="' + url + '">' + title +
            '</a><br>ID: ' + id;
      } else if (action == google.picker.Action.CANCEL) {
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Picker canceled.';
      }
    }

    function showError(message) {
      document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Error: ' + message;
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <button onclick='getOAuthToken()'>Select a file</button>
    <p id='result'></p>
  </div>
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=onApiLoad"></script>
</body>
<script>
function showPicker() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('PickerHTML2.html')
      .setWidth(600)
      .setHeight(425)
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Select a file');
}

function getOAuthToken() {
  DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  return ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
}
</script>

</html>
```

When I try to run this code its showing error.

thank you in advance to everybody for any help or advice.

Comment: The driveApp is a class from apps script, see [Class DriveApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app). What are you trying to do with the DriveApp on the HTML?

Comment: i am trying to make a google drive picker.
have you any example? 
i am trying above code but its not working.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/picker/guides/sample
i also try this example but still is not showing me the google drive picker.

Comment: Can you describe where are you inserting this code? On the code sample there is no `DriveApp`